# How do I find the source of empty items in my Explorer context menu?

Tags: windows-explorer

When I open the context menu for certain files (image files as far as I can tell), I see empty spaces in the menu:

[image]

How can I find what the source of these are?

Answer (score 1):

Nirsoft's *ShellExView* displays the source of context menu entries; see http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html.
Sysinternals' *Autoruns for Windows* shows not only Explorer context menu entries in the *Explorer* tab but also a slew of other items that run automatically; see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx.

If one is not the obvious culprit, you can disable a few context menu entries at a time until the blank entries are gone [binary search].

Comment: I have 311 shell extensions installed. Could be quite the job to work through those. But ShellExView is a nice hint.

Comment: Narrow it down to the type of context menu where the blanks appear, e.g. image files. The new *Autoruns* also has an option to hide Microsoft entries, which should reduce your search.